# ANTLR 3 parsing - mismatched character ... expecting

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am quiete a newbie in ANTLR and I looked around for a while to fix my problem. Unfortunately without any success...

I simplified my grammar to describe the problem (the token TAG is used in the real example):

```
grammar Test;

WORD : ('a'..'z')+;

DOT : '.';

TAG : '.test';

WHITE_SPACE
    :   (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};


rule
    :   'a' DOT WORD 'z';
```

When I try to parse the word "a .bcd z" everything is fine, but when I try the word "a .tbyfa z" it shows me the error

```
line 1:4 mismatched character 'b' expecting 'e'
line 1:5 missing DOT at 'yfa'
```

In my opinion the problem is that the string after the "." starts with a "t" which could also be the token ".test". I tried backtrack=true, but also without any success.
How can I fix that problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ".test" is a keyword. the dot in ".test" has a different meaning than the DOT token.

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR's lexer cannot backtrack to an alternative in this case. Once the lexer *sees* `".t"`, it tries to match the `TAG` token, but this doesn't succeed, so the lexer then tries to match something else that starts with `".t"`, but there is no such token. And the lexer will *not* backtrack a character again to match a `DOT`. So that's what's going wrong.

A possible solution to it would be to do it like this:

```
grammar Test;

rule  : 'a' DOT WORD 'z';
WORD  : ('a'..'z')+;
DOT   : '.' (('test')=> 'test' {$type=TAG;})?;
SPACE :  (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};

fragment TAG : /* empty rule: only used to change the 'type' */;
```

The `('test')=>` is a syntactic predicate which forces the lexer to look ahead to see if there really is `"test"` ahead. If this is true, `"test"` is matched and the type of the token is changed to `TAG`. And since `'test'` is optional, the rule can always fall back on only the `DOT` token.

Comment: I have got another question now. How can I handle more tokens in the form ".xyz", like ".test" and ".test2". DOT   : '.' (('test2')=> 'test2' {$type=TAG2;} | ('test')=> 'test' {$type=TAG1;} )?;...

Comment: Ok cool, but if i wanna use TAG1 and TAG2 as a token in the parser it will be a problem (TAG1 and TAG2 without the fragment). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No, you *can* use these empty fragment rules in parser rules. It's a bit of a hack, but that's the way it works :)

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but during playing around I got a new problem... 
the following string "a .test z" does not work. Is there any way to tell the parser that she should use DOT WORD instead of TAG?

Comment: @user1286372, no, the parser works independently from the lexer. `'.test'` will always become a `TAG`, never a `DOT` and `WORD`. You'll have to account for this in the parser rule: `rule : 'a' (DOT WORD | TAG) 'z';`